# Active Admin Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Active Admin has an opinionated way of showing associations that works excellent as long as the association has a field called name. I know there's a way to tell Active Admin which field to show from the associated file but I cannot find it anywhere in the documentation.

I have a model called `app_label_translation` that belongs_to `app_label`. `app_label` has a field called `label` that I'd like Active Admin treat as it would a field named `name`.

As a work-around I'm doing this:

```
  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
      column :app_label, sortable: "app_labels.label" do |a|
      link_to a.app_label.label admin_app_label_path(a.app_label)
    end
  end
```

Does anyone know the command to override name with a field of your choice?

**Update**: I'm using a slightly better work-around now by having `alias_attribute :name, :label` in my `app_label` model. This allows active admin to do its thing with label. I still think there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in another argument before the model you want to display in the column.

Taken from their documentation: http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html

```
index do
  selectable_column
  column "My Custom Title", :title
end
```

That should do the trick.